# Per-value statistics over table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to generate statistics per value for a column in a table, generating the value itself, number of occurrences of that value in the table, and the % of that from the total.

I have a table such as in the following example:

```
                Table "public.films"
       Column |         Type          | Modifiers
      --------+-----------------------+-----------
       code   | character(5)          |
       title  | character varying(40) |


      # select * from films;
       code  | title
      -------+-------
       a1123 | yo1
       a1124 | yo1
       a1125 | yo2
       a110  | yo3
       a110v | yo3
       a1a   | yo3
       a1az  | yo3
      (7 rows)
```

I tried using rank() and percent_rank() to accomplish this but it didn't work. Expected outcome for the above example would be:

```
      # select * from films;
       title | title_count | title_percent
      -------+-------------+-------------------
       yo1   | 2           | 28%
       yo2   | 1           | 14%
       yo3   | 4           | 57%
```

What's the most efficient query to achieve that goal, considering that the table will contain over 100 millions of values? (the column is indexed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
SELECT title,
       COUNT(*) AS title_count,
       ROUND(COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100) AS percent
  FROM films
 GROUP
    BY title
 ORDER
    BY title
```

Comment: Thanks, simple & works! i do hope this won't be slow for large tables, accepted as all the other answers are derivatives of this

Answer (score 1):

And yet another one:

```
WITH code_cnt AS (
    SELECT title, count(*) AS title_count
    FROM films
    GROUP BY title),
  gt AS (
    SELECT sum(title_count) AS grand_total
    FROM code_cnt)
SELECT title, title_count, (100 * title_count / grand_total) AS title_percent
FROM code_cnt, gt
ORDER BY title;
```

This version avoids the use of `count(*)` on the entire table, which is a performance issue when the table is large. (Note that the first three answers calculate both all records in the entire table and then separately for each group.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient query though:

```
with total (total_count) as (
  select count(*)::numeric
  from films
)
select title, 
       count(*) as title_count, 
       (count(*)::numeric / (select total_count from total)) * 100  as title_percent
from films
group by title
order by title;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title
    ,title_count
    ,(
        (
            title_count / (
                SELECT count(*)::NUMERIC
                FROM films
                )
            ) * 100
        )::INT title_percent
FROM (
    SELECT title
        ,count(title)::NUMERIC title_count
    FROM films
    GROUP BY title
    ORDER BY title
    ) t;
```

Result :

```
title title_count title_percent 
----- ----------- ------------- 
yo1   2           29            
yo2   1           14            
yo3   4           57
```

---

```
SELECT title
    ,title_count
    ,(
        (
            title_count / (
                SELECT count(*)::NUMERIC
                FROM films
                )
            ) * 100
        )::INT::TEXT || '%' title_percent
FROM (
    SELECT title
        ,count(title)::NUMERIC title_count
    FROM films
    GROUP BY title
    ORDER BY title
    ) t;
```

Result :

```
title title_count title_percent 
----- ----------- ------------- 
yo3   4           57%           
yo1   2           29%           
yo2   1           14%
```